# Can android System App (privileged) read or copy /data/tombstones

Tags: android, tombstone

I've my app as system-priv and build along with my AOSP code. now my app needs to copy the tombstone folder which is under /data/tombstones to /sdcard.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it worked.

There are 2 parts

i) You've to register tombstones path using FileObserver, so whenever new tombstone created you'll get the callback.
ii) Your app should have the permission to read this path otherwise you'll get an avc denied due to SELinux. So add permission to system_app.te file of sepolicy.

Comment: Hi im having the same usecase, but above solutions did not work, kindly share the code snippet for both the parts. Thanks in advance.